# Border colors in TListView (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, tlistview

I am trying to customize Background color and font color of a ListView item using OnCustomDrawItem event. However, the border color of subitem is always the background color of ListView. Does anyone know how to fix this? Here is the code i am using:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
  Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  lst: TListView;
  i: integer;
  f1, f2, c1, c2: TColor;
begin
  if (TListView(Sender).ViewStyle = vsIcon) then
    Exit;
  lst := Sender as TListView;
  lst.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
  i := lst.Items.Count;
  if (i mod 2) <> 0 then
  begin
    c1 := clWhite;
    c2 := $00F8F8F8;
    f1 := clBlue;
    f2 := clBlack;
  end else
  begin
    c1 := $00F8F8F8;
    c2 := clWhite;
    f1 := clBlack;
    f2 := clBlue;
  end;
  // Painting...
  if (Item.Index mod 2) = 0 then
  begin
    lst.Canvas.Brush.Color := c2;
    lst.Canvas.Font.Color := f2;
  end else
  begin
    lst.Canvas.Brush.Color := c1;
    lst.Canvas.Font.Color := f1;
  end;
end;
```

EDIT:

There is a GAP between column of SubItems. This GAP is the color of ListView's background.

I use Delphi XE2 and OS: Windows 7 bit bit.

Comment: Hint: Replace `(Item.Index mod 2) = 0` by `Odd(Item.Index)` (or the negation of the last statement).

Comment: Btw, there is a gap between columns of subitems... and this gap is the color of listview

Comment: Btw, I use XE2 and Win7 64bit

Comment: Are you sure it is not themed? By default apps are themed. Perhaps you thought I was asking if you used VCL styles. If your app is not themed then you would have had to remove the comctl32 v6 manifest. Did you do that?

Comment: Oppsss.. My mistake then. Yes it is themed. How can i remove this theme from code?

Comment: Ok, I have removed theming. But now, all application is not themed :)

Comment: I didn't ask you to remove theming. I just wanted to know whether or not your app was themed. Now, custom drawing of themed controls is very hard to get right. Typically you have to paint the entire control yourself. Using the theme API.

Comment: Hmm.. Yes it seems hard to do

Answer (score 1):

Try OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem instead your CustomDrawItem procedure

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1AdvancedCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView;
Item: TListItem; State: TCustomDrawState; Stage: TCustomDrawStage;
var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  lst: TListView;
  i: integer;
  f1, f2, c1, c2: TColor;
  r: TRect;
begin
  if Stage = cdPostPaint then
  begin
    lst := Sender as TListView;
    lst.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
    i := lst.Items.Count;
    if not Odd(i) then
    begin
      c1 := clWhite;
      c2 := $00F8F8F8;
      f1 := clBlue;
      f2 := clBlack;
    end else
    begin
      c1 := $00F8F8F8;
      c2 := clWhite;
      f1 := clBlack;
      f2 := clBlue;
    end;
    // Painting...
    if Odd(Item.Index) then
    begin
      lst.Canvas.Brush.Color := c2;
      lst.Canvas.Pen.Color := c2;
      lst.Canvas.Font.Color := f2;
    end else
    begin
      lst.Canvas.Brush.Color := c1;
      lst.Canvas.Pen.Color := c1;
      lst.Canvas.Font.Color := f1;
    end;

    r:=Item.DisplayRect(drBounds);

    if cdsSelected in State then
    begin
      lst.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clHighlight;
      lst.Canvas.Pen.Color:=clHighlight;
      lst.Canvas.Font.Color:=clBlack;
    end;

    lst.Canvas.Rectangle(r);

    if cdsSelected in State then
      lst.Canvas.DrawFocusRect(r);

    lst.Canvas.TextOut(r.Left, r.Top + (r.Bottom - r.top - lst.Canvas.TextHeight(Item.Caption)) div 2, Item.Caption);
    for i := 0 to Item.SubItems.Count - 1 do
    begin
      r.Left:=r.Left + lst.Columns[i].Width;
      lst.Canvas.TextOut(r.Left, r.Top + (r.Bottom - r.top - lst.Canvas.TextHeight(Item.Caption)) div 2, Item.SubItems[i]);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work as expected. All I want to do is to get rid of GAP being filled by background color